# Save datagridview from child form in a SQL database in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, forms, datagridview

In C#, I have a form named "Details" which displays a datagridview with a ticket number and a "done" column (with other information I don't want to save).

For example:

```
    Ticket Number | Done
   _______________|________ 
       252014     |  v   
       252018     |     
       252024     |  v  
       252029     |  v
```

Users have to check or uncheck the "done" columns with checkbox then close the form and press "Save" on the "main" form (which contains other information to save in a SQL database).

I'm trying to find a way to save the list of "ticket number" and "done" in a public list, then save this list in a SQL database on the main form. I think it's the simplest way but can't find how to keep ticket number and the done-status in the same list.

Comment: Please show us the relevant C# code you have.

Comment: There is nowhere near enough information here to help. What part(s) are you having trouble with? What have you tried?

Comment: If `Details` is your child form, then you can go in the code-behind and change the accessor of the `DataGridView` from `private` to `public`.  Then, even when your child form is closed, the parent can still access the the child's `DataGridView` directly for this data. No need to store it anywhere else.

Comment: Sorry for not showing my code, I was looking for an idea runway, I had nothing functional. I choose the @OhBeWise solution, a datagridview public. Simple and efficient, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use DataBindings. First you have to implement a class for your Ticket. This can be as simple as

```
class Ticket
{
    public Ticket(string Number)
    {
        this.Number = Number;
    }

    public bool IsDone
    {
        set { _IsDone = value; }
        get { return _IsDone; }
    }

    public string Number
    {
        set { _Number = value; }
        get { return _Number; }
    }

    private bool _IsDone = false;
    private string _Number = "";
}
```

Now you have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` so the UI can update.

```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
    }
```

Of course you have to call the `OnPropertyChanged` function in the setters of `IsDone` and `Number`.

```
set 
{
    _IsDone = value;
    OnPropertyChanged("IsDone");
}
```

(...)

```
set 
{
    _Number = value;
    OnPropertyChanged("Number");
}
```

In your Form you have to define an `ObservableCollection<Ticket>` for your `DataGridView`. Use `Add` to add all Tickets to it.

In your class of the form

```
private ObservableCollection<Ticket> Tickets;
```

In the constructor

```
Tickets = new ObservableCollection<Ticket>();
YourDataGridName.ItemsSource = Tickets;
Tickets.Add(new Ticket("TicketNumber"));
```

With

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ticket Number" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Number}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Done?" IsReadOnly="False" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding IsDone}"></DataGridTextColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

you define the columns for the `DataGridView`.
The form now have to return the ObservableCollection (you can convert it to a List before) to your main form. The main form can now check with `.IsDone` wether the box was checked or not.

Comment: Thank you for the time you took to offer me a solution. I prefer to set my datagridview in public and INSERT in a for loop. But I keep your solution for next problems, it can be helpful.